# What could be wrong with my laptop, which shuts down unexpectedly?

Tags: laptop, battery, power

I've searched quite a few forums and questions on this website, but felt like none matched my exact problem.

Simply said, my laptop shuts down without any notice. By 'shut down' in this question I always mean: turns off immediately, without following the correct procedure for shutting down. This instant shutdown also seems to imply that the laptop takes a much longer time to boot the first time after, but I don't think permanent damage is caused after such a 'crash'. At least I hope so.

This problem only occurs when the charger is not connected to the laptop, thus, pretty much ruling out the possibility that there is a heating problem or something similar. Even when the battery is removed and the charger is plugged in, no problems occur. I tested this extensively, but the problems just never occur when the charger is plugged in, not even when playing a computer game, for example.

Since my battery was over two and a half years old and had been used a lot, I decided to buy a new one, thinking that I could use the extra capacity even if battery turned out not to be the culprit. With the new battery, the problem persists. The shutdowns might have become slightly less frequent, but I haven't tested this so thoroughly.

Just to clarify: the problem is *not* that the battery charge indicator is broken and the laptop shuts down because the battery is dead. After such a shutdown, I can start my computer without connecting the charger and continue working. Today, I worked for three hours on battery power, without recharging. In these three hours, four shutdowns occured, spread more or less equally in time.

I have already reinstalled my operating system (Windows 10), but to no avail. In fact, the problem (still with my old battery) existed before updating from Windows 8 to 10. I have an anti-virus programme which is up to date. I have not yet completely reset the computer and wiped the harddrive; I would like to keep this as a last resort, for obvious reasons.

As a non-expert, the only thing I can think of is a hardware problem, some kind of faulty communication between the battery and the system. I'd rather not have my laptop tinkered with unnecessarily, so I'd like to hear your opinion before bringing my laptop to the manufacturer (and paying a high price, as the warranty has already expired).

Looking forward to hearing from you

Comment: Are there any errors in the event viewer prior to the shutdown/restart?

Comment: You mean the last seconds before the shutdown? No, the only thing I notice is that my computer slows down a bit the last two seconds before shutdown (e.g. my keyboard or cursor get less responsive).
I've just tried to change the battery settings to 'power saving'. Have only tried this for a few hours, so might be a coincidence, but have had no more shutdowns.

Answer (score 1):

Like you I believe this to be a hardware fault.

I am not 100% convinced that it is not overheating, it is possible that you have different max CPU frequency set in the advanced power options, however I find it very unlikely you set the max frequency to be lower when on power than on battery but it is a possibility.  I mention this as you stated the unit is slower after it is restarted which would suggest CPU throttling to try and maintain a lower temp.

It possibly could be an issue with the battery management/power converter, if the laptop tries to draw too much current from the battery (ie due to a fault) then the battery protection mechanism (part of battery normally) will kick in to prevent thermal runaway (fire and brimstone) in the battery by cutting the juice.

If any peripherals are connected they may be failing and shorting out the USB ports which can also cause this issue.

In general if a computer powers itself straight off with no warning then you are looking at a fault, with a laptop it will be a motherboard fault (you have swap tested battery) that will need board level repairs / replacement.

Hope you get it sorted :)

Comment: THis is not an answer and should be in a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll check the CPU frequency settings. If I understand your answer correctly, this is the last thing I should try before bringing the laptop to the manufacturer? There are no devices connected to the laptop, if that's what you mean by peripherals.

Comment: @Xavierjazz I await your answer to determine why mine is merely a comment as you have some way of determining the exact fault from the information supplied (which was really good btw a step up from most).

Comment: @Bib-lost you have a fault which needs repair, you may be able to work-around it by reducing max CPU freq if it is indeed overheating. :)

Comment: I really doubt that actual overheating might be the cause. When e.g. playing a computer game, the fans turn to a higher speed than when just browsing the net, but this does not affect the frequency of the crashes. But I'll just check if there are no weird settings for the CPU frequency when on battery, just to be sure. I'll have access to my laptop in an hour or so.

Comment: Checked the settings for power management, nothing unusual. I also have Speedfan, which does not report any overheating.

Comment: I agree that it's not likely to be overheating given your info which is a shame as that would normally be an easy cheap fix such as replacing the thermal compound between CPU and the heatsink fan assembly or if necessary the entire heatsink fan assembly.  If you want you could run some bootable diagnostics, look for ultimate boot cd (UBCD) or hirens boot disk and run some tests on loop and see if the machine falls over during them ruling out software.  Beware the tests don't work backwards, if it completes the tests without failing it DOES NOT indicate a software fault specifically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36185/discussion-between-bib-lost-and-n-searle).

Comment: @Xavierjazz:  N_Searle's post is good material, but too long to fit inside a comment.  I believe that an answer is an okay place for it to be.

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop is shut down  without any warning then I have mentioned some of the steps that you can  check once:

Method 1: Change the Battery Settings in the Power Plan

Every power plan comes with different settings for hard disk, desktop background, USB, Sleep mode, battery and more. Now, the battery settings of a power plan also come with different options where you are allowed to configure the battery levels or notifications. Similarly, you can make changes to the battery notifications that may fix the issue. Let’s see how:

Step 1: Go to the Taskbar Search of Windows 10.

Step 2:  search Edit power plan.

Step 3: Click on Edit Power plan.

Step 4: Next, in the „Edit Plan Settings“ window, click on the „Change advanced power settings“ link towards the bottom

Step 5: This will open the Power Options > Advanced Settings dialogue box.
Now, in the list, click on the plus sign next to Battery to expand the section.

Step 6: Again, click on the plus symbol to expand the Low battery notification option.

Make sure that On battery and Plugged in options are ON.

If not, click on the drop-down next to On battery and Plugged in options one by one and set them to ON status.

Step 7: Next, press the „Restore plan defaults“ button below.

Step 8: Once done, press Apply and then OK to save the changes and exit.

Close the Control Panel window and see if this is working.
Or you can check if all the hardware is properly connected. if any loose connections this may cause to shut down. Sometimes this also happens because of RAM. So try cleaning the RAM and again put it in place.
Finally, if nothing works check for a computer hardware person. As this may increase your problem if not solved in time.